# Can prepending "junk" be equivalent to an IV when encrypting using CBC?

Tags: aes, initialization-vector, cbc

We are encrypting a small positive integer (1-1000) with a constant key using AES256 encryption.  We are considering two approaches to make this secure; use an initial vector (which we then need to store as well), or just prepend some junk to the integer before encryption (possibly 6 characters, this is the plaintext we might encrypt to store 123: "fI8cW3123").

The second approach seems better to us, (we only store a single value, and "discover" the IV while decrypting), but we aren't cryptography experts.  Is this dangerous or less secure?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Storing and transmitting an IV requires an extra 32 bytes. Why spend time, effort, and energy brainstorming ways to avoid dealing with *thirty two bytes*? I'm sure you have tons of problems that actually require solving, and I can't imagine that figuring out how to handle thirty two bytes is one of them.

Comment: Choose n uniformly from [0,2^118) and then store AES(k,(1000*n)+123). $\hspace{1.7 in}$

Comment: +1 Stephen In anycase you have to ensure that the IV is a nonce. If you are always using the same key this consideration is critical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that the integer is fixed in size (always in the range 1-1000), then the second approach is fine.  Effectively, you still have a random nonce (what you are calling the "junk"); you concatenate the nonce and the integer, then encrypt the result with AES-ECB.  This works.

Do make sure that you choose a large enough random nonce.  I recommend making it as large as possible, i.e., filling the full remaining width of the block.  For instance, if your value is always in the range 1-1000, then it will fit in 10 bits.  So dedicate 10 bits to hold the value, and use the other 118 bits for the random nonce (i.e., to encrypt, you generate a random 118-bit nonce, concatenate it with the value, and then encrypt using AES-ECB).  At a minimum, you probably want your nonce to be at least 80 bits long, and a bit longer might be a bit better.

Also, make sure that you use a cryptographic-strength PRNG to generate the random nonce.